# is There some function that make a conversion from string to array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

```
string x = "Banana";
```

How do I convert it to a char like this:

```
char x[]={'B', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a'};
```

Comment: [`string::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)?

Comment: Remember in standard c++ an array must have a fixed size at compile time.

Comment: Yeah i know this just an example

Comment: `std::string` already manages an array of `char`. What do you need it for? What's the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `.data()` and `.c_str()` should be enough. What do you need it for?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can follow this way in c++ to convert a string into array of characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // assigning value to string s
    string s = "Banana";
 
    int n = s.length();
 
    // declaring character array
    char char_array[n + 1];
 
    // copying the contents of the
    // string to char array
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());
 
    // this part need to be deleted. This is only for verification.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << char_array[i] << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char char_array[n + 1];` is not standard C++... An array need a constant size.

Comment: And there's no reason to have a separate array. Everything you can do with an array, you can do with the string itself.